# If $R$ is a UFD, then every prime element of $R$ generates a prime ideal

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, unique-factorization-domains

The hint in my book says:

If $p$ is prime element of $R$ $\implies$ $p$ is irreducible element of $R$ $\implies$  $\langle p\rangle$ is maximal ideal of $R$ $\implies$ $\langle p\rangle$ is prime ideal of $R$.

I am stuck with the second implication

> $p$ is irreducible element of $R$ $\implies$  $\langle p\rangle$ is maximal ideal
>   of $R$

Being a beginner, I know this holds for a $PID$, but could not proceed for a $UFD$. Some reasoning for the above implication would be very helpful.

**NOTE:** $\langle p\rangle$ denotes the principal ideal generated by $p$.

Comment: < and > should (mostly) only ever be used for inequalities in typesetting. In this case, please use \langle and \rangle since these don't have a ton of whitespace.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you for the edit, I am still learning to typeset.

Comment: Can you clarify what your definition of a prime element is? For me, an element $p$ is prime if whenever $p\mid ab$, $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. This is always equivalent to $\langle p\rangle$ being prime.

Comment: Moreover, the assertion $p$ irreducible $\implies$ $\langle p\rangle$ maximal is false! Consider $\langle X\rangle$ in $\mathbb Z[X]$.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha No worries! I've seen lecture notes from esteemed faculty that use < and > "wrongly"..

Comment: @Mathmo123 We use the same definition for prime elements as you stated.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha there is something very fishy here... you're being asked to prove something that is always true, and the hint just doesn't work (see my second comment)!

Comment: @Mathmo123 I agree with your example. That's why I am stuck with this hint.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha do you have a reference for the book?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Its a local textbook motivated from *Topics in Algebra by Herstein*